# Magento attributes - Disable HTML stripout

Tags: magento, attributes

When setting up new attributes in Magento is it possible to disable the stripping out of html tags in the attribute?

The reason I ask is that I would like to put some product information in to an attribute but it needs formatting in a specific way, if I try to paste any HTML formatting in the options it strips it out.

I need to be able to select something from a dropdown menu in the admin section then for the frontend to show the formatted text relevent.

Alternatively if there is a way to call a specific static block depending on what attribute is selected that would be great.

Comment: Enable WYSIWYG from attribute options

Comment: It's not a WYSIWYG related issue.

Comment: If you find yourself needing to enter markup in the attribute value then you're probably doing it wrong.  Would it be easier to split it up into multiple attributes.. then you can handle the presentation of the data in the presentation layer.  Imagine how annoying it will be later down the line when you need to change the formatting of this data and you have to do it for every product ;)

Comment: That's the thing though.. the way I want to do it is as a selectable dropdown in the back end the content will be entered only once as an choice, so if something needed changing it would be one change in the attribute that would change across the board.

Comment: As usual Alan Storm has a great article to address this exact issue I believe.
http://alanstorm.com/magento_html5_tinymce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved... ended up using this code to call a static block with the same name as a predefined attribute.

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId($_product->getAttributeText('availability'))->toHTML();?>
```